# PSU Patch on 2 standby database

Tags: oracle

We have  one Primary have 2 standby database... so we planning to PSU patch on Primar and one standby only in that case when we  running catundle on primary it any problem for another standby which we are not applied patch ?

Can any one help on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parts to patching.
1.software binaries patching the binaries and library files
2. The database objects that rough catbundle or dispatch.

It may not cause any problems directly not patching the database component but there would be some conflicts and issues with functionality.It may also be not supported by oracle. It is advisable to keep primary and all standby databases at the same level.

The database component in the standby database would automatically be updated during the replication.